# Windows Service to get latest posts

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-fql, status

I'm writing a service (C#) that gets all the latest posts and comments from FB. I initially used "/feed", but soon realised I couldn't filter on date. So, I turned to Fql and am querying the stream table for latest posts. Trouble with this is that it doesn't give comments. So, I query the comments table, but that doesn't allow filtering by date - only the post_id, but this means I have to iterate through all my existing posts in order to find a comment, which is not efficient. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I don't know where you get your information, but you are stating falsehoods.

> I initially used "/feed", but soon realised I couldn't filter on date.

It is possible to filter by date on the graph. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

> So, I query the comments table, but that doesn't allow filtering by date

It is possible to filter by date in FQL. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment's time column.